# How to manage Activity instances in Android

Tags: android, android-activity, activity-stack

I have an initial activity `O` and one more activity `A` in which i can select to go to activities `A1,A2,A3` and for example fill in a form in each of them. So i follow this path:

> O>A>A1>A>A2>A>A3

While i am at `A3` i want to press the back button and go to `O` again but i will have to pass from every instance of A (let's assume i use `finish()` or `no history` in the manifest for `A1,A2,A3` so they will be not present in the stack)

how can i declare that `A` will only have one instance (the last one) in the stack, so that if i press back button twice i will go to `O` again?

Comment: Each time activity `A` appears is a new instance? Why not just have a single instance of activity `A` and go back to it from each of the other activities?

Comment: this is default behavior. How can i make it single instance? that's the question...

Comment: why do u need to create multiple instance of A? are u implementing logout functionalities?

Comment: Are A1, A2, A3 and A all instances of the same `Activity` class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
  @Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Intent intent = new Intent(this,O.class);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
    startActivity(intent);
    finish();
}
```

Comment: While this answer is good, try to explain what the code does, to help other/new users understand how it works. Most Android begginners have problems understanding `Activity` and `Task` stacks.

Answer (score 1):

Change the [`launchMode`](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#lmode) of activity `A` to `singleTop`. As it states in the documentation:

> If an instance of the activity already exists at the top of the target
>   task, the system routes the intent to that instance through a call to
>   its onNewIntent() method, rather than creating a new instance of the
>   activity.

Now, instead of going from `A -> A1 -> A`, you can just `finish()` activity `A1` (or use the [*up* button](https://developer.android.com/training/implementing-navigation/ancestral.html)), which will return you to the instance of activity `A`.